# Can't create dir with slash in dir name

Tags: php

Using php 7 on mac os x, I can't create a folder with php `mkdir()` if the folder name has a slash in it, e.g. `Test 24/04/2015`.

Here's my PHP code:

```
$FolderPath = readline("Insert Folder Path "); // I enter /Users/me/Test 24/04/2015
echo "You have entered: " . $FolderPath;
echo "\n";
echo "\n";

$FolderPathResized = $FolderPath . "/Resized";

if (file_exists($FolderPathResized)) {
    echo "The folder $FolderPathResized exists";
    echo "\n";
}else {
    mkdir($FolderPathResized);
}
```

The error I get is:

```
mkdir(): No such file or directory in
```

How can I use `mkdir()` in such case? My folders will always have dates separates with slashes in the folder name.

Comment: You can't even manually create such directory name. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10708449/5447994)

Comment: And even if: that would be a _really_ bad idea: how to you want to use it afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create directory names with a `/` in it. Use a `_` would be better to separate the date.

This can be done with using the function `str_replace()` to replace all `/` with `_` in your date.

The error is being shown because it captures the first / and attempts to write it in such a directory and it doesn't exist. You will have to encase it in quotes for it to be read in the first place.

Comment: This is not really an answer. It should have been a comment.

Comment: He asked how to use mkdir() in such a case. In this case, the only way he can use it is to replace all `_` with `/` to prevent it from being read as the root directory. His error obviously shows that it is reading from the root directory.

Comment: All I said is: this did not answer the question. And _maybe_ there is a reason why you need a minimum reputation to comment...

Comment: His question was how can he use mkdir() when his dates separates with a slash. My answer to that is to replace all `/` with `_` , how is that not an answer to his question?

Comment: It does not achieve what the OP asks for.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Worked with the "_" instead of "/", will try to modify all folder as such so wont have any issues in the future. Though dont understand why the down vote, seriously. I am a beginner in programming and I can't even understand why my question was down voted when for me seems ok to ask because I couldnt understand why mkdir() didnt worked... Anyway thank you very much for the answers.

Comment: If I have answered your question, a upvote and a check would be nice :)

Comment: @Ctc I tried to give you an upvote but it gave me this in reply "  Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score " :((( ...

Comment: @user6387363 its okay :) glad I helped!

Comment: @Ctc I earned 15 reputations, I will gladly give the upvote now :) !

Answer (score 0):

You probably have found the answer since this question is 4 years old, but if you want to create a folder with a slash in the name, you can do like this:

```
mkdir My\:Folder
```

It will create a folder with name = "My/Folder"

Hope it helps someone :)