# My code shows error msg while saving a file with date and time in the file name

Tags: excel, vba

i am using the code below to save a file with date and time in the file name. Unfortunately, it shows **error** msg. Is there a way to avoid this error?

```
dim a as variant
dim fname as string
dim newWB as workbooks
a = Now()
fname = CStr(a)
Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
newWB.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\0003079\Downloads\QiraTickets" & "(" & fname & ")", FileFormat:=56
```

Comment: Because your `fname` have `:` which are not allowed in File Name.

Comment: what Mikku said.  [Slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708334/how-can-i-create-files-on-windows-with-embedded-slashes-using-python) ('/') and [colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386344/how-to-get-a-file-in-windows-with-a-colon-in-the-filename) (':') are not allowed in windows file names

Answer (score 0):

**Problems:**

- Use of `:` in filename isn't allowed
- Declaration as Workbooks, should be `workbook`

**Try:**

```
Dim a As Variant
Dim fname As String
Dim newWB As Workbook

a = Now()

fname = Replace(CStr(a), ":", "'")

Set newWB = Workbooks.Add

newWB.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\0003079\Downloads\QiraTickets" & "(" & fname & ")", FileFormat:=56
```

Yellow highlighted are not allowed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> From Mikku and McAlex: Slash ('/') and colon (':') are not allowed in
>   windows file names.

However, you can format your date output to something useful before you assign it to the filename

```
dim a as Date ' <-- always strongly type when you can
dim fname as string
dim newWB as workbook  ' Workbook, not Workbooks
a = Now()  ' Assuming that you want to use a later
fname = Format(a, "yymmdd hhnnss") ' <-- Format will output a string
Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
newWB.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\0003079\Downloads\QiraTickets" & "(" & fname & ")", FileFormat:=56
```

Of course, if `a` is only used to form the file name, we can tidy this up.

```
Dim fname As String
Dim newWB As Workbook
fname = "C:\Users\0003079\Downloads\QiraTickets(" & Format(Now(), "yymmdd hhnnss") & ")" 
Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
newWB.SaveAs Filename:= fname, FileFormat:=56
```