# R markdown can't save file

Tags: r

Tried to save my R markdown document as a file in a folder. File to save as and then put it in my lab folder. Titled the r document R-Lab6/7.rmd and it does not let me save the file. The error is "Error file not found".

Comment: Does the folder itself exist? You would need to create the folder first if not. How exactly are you saving the file?

Comment: `getwd()`, `list.files()`

Comment: Those also may not be the best file names, I try to only you underscores, no `/` or  `-`, but that’s just me

Comment: oops, I didn't see that you said "in a folder!" revising my answer again ...

Answer (score 2):

The folder/directory must already exist before you can save a file into it. You can either create the folder outside of R (in your operating system's file browser, or in RStudio's "files" panel), or you can use `dir.create("R-Lab6")` from the R console.

Here's an illustration of the problem, using command-line functions:

```
save("x", file="a/b.rda")
```

> Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
> In addition: Warning message:
> In gzfile(file, "wb") :
> cannot open compressed file 'a/b.rda', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

Now create the directory `a`:

```
dir.create("a")
```

and saving works

```
save("x", file="a/b.rda")
```

So it has now saved a file called `b.rda` in directory `a` (not a file called `a/b.rda`).

---

I originally thought/misunderstood that you wanted to include a `/` in your file name.

While modern tools allow you to use almost any characters you like in a file name, slashes are almost never allowed, because they are used by the operating system to denote that a file is contained in a directory (in [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708334/how-can-i-create-files-on-windows-with-embedded-slashes-using-python) and [on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288/is-it-possible-to-use-in-a-filename) and [almost always on MacOS](https://www.cnet.com/news/managing-files-with-forward-slashes-in-their-names/)).

Once you start dealing with programming, it's safest not only to avoid slashes (which are impossible) but also other "special" characters: use only numbers, letters, and simple punctuation (dash `-`, underscore `_`, and dot `.`) in your file names ...