# Why can't I make a file with a name like "InternetSpeedTest_11/24/21.csv"?

Tags: python

I have a script that I will run repeatedly. I want it to log results to output files, using a different file each day. I decided to use the date in the file name, like so:

```
from os import exists
from datetime.datetime import now

data = "example data,123.456"

filename = 'InternetSpeedTest_' + now.strftime("%D") + '.csv'
if exists(filename):
    with open(filename, 'a+') as f:
        f.seek(0, 0)
        a = f.read()
        f.write('\n')
        f.write(data)
else:
    with open(filename, 'w+') as f:
        f.write(data)
```

But this gives me an error when it tries to open the file (either to start a new one or to append):

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'InternetSpeedTest_11/24/21.csv'
```

I've also tried specifying an absolute path to the file, but the problem remains.

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filename is being treated as several subdirectories then a file, namely

```
InternetSpeetTest_11/
  24/
    21.csv
```

Therefore the "No such file or directory" error is telling you those intermediate directories do not exist. Instead switch to something that doesn't look like a directory such as

```
'InternetSpeedTest_11-24-21.csv'
```

Comment: Thank you!! The answer was staring me in the face the whole time! The proper change to the datetime input: you can get rid of the / by using %d%m%y rather than %D

Comment: Additional note: While on Windows `/` doesn't separate directories, it is still [explicitly forbidden in file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708334/how-can-i-create-files-on-windows-with-embedded-slashes-using-python) (and many languages/APIs will thus accept `/` as a directory separator, even on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of operating system, `/` will be treated as a path separator, and cannot be part of the file name. Attempting to use a name like `InternetSpeedTest_11/24/21.csv` will actually try to use the name `21.csv` inside the subfolder `24` of the folder `InternetSpeedTest_11`. This causes an error - not just wrong results - because [opening a file for writing will not create intermediate folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758673).

The standard way to include dates in file names is to use [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601): YYYY-MM-DD. Putting the year first, and using zero-padded numbers for the month and day, ensures that file names that vary only in the date will sort chronologically.

Python's [`datetime`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150739), `date` and `time` classes all provide a `isoformat` method which can be used to convert, without needing to remember any formatting codes. Thus:

```
from os import exists
from datetime.datetime import now

data = "example data,123.456"

filename = f'InternetSpeedTest_{now.date().isoformat()}.csv'
if exists(filename):
    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        f.write(data)
```

This will append the `data` to a file named like `InternetSpeedTest_2021-24-11.csv`, creating it first if it doesn't exist.